# Convert NULL value to blank string in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

As the title says I'm trying to convert null values to empty strings.
I'm using the following code:

```
ISNULL((DT_WSTR,10,1252)[Serial No.])?"" : (DT_WSTR,10,1252)[Serial No.]
```

It returns: 
[image]

I've tried several similar solutions as above, they all returns the same.

Update: Why I need this.
Got 4 columns (Serial No. included), which I need to combine into one column, this is done in derived column:
((DT_STR,150,1252)([Col1]) + (DT_STR,150,1252)([Col2]) + (DT_STR,150,1252)([Serial No.]) + (DT_STR,150,1252)(Col4))

In case one of these is NULL, it will be combined to : NULL.
Therefore it can't be used in Lookup which is the next step.

Comment: But why do you try to do that? An empty string is not the same as NULL...

Comment: The table contains null values in the column. I need them to be blank.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but I can't understand why you need them to be blank...

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I'm not familiar with SSIS, but when I want NULL values to be represented by something else, for example an empty string or `0`, I use the `COALESCE()` function:  `SELECT COALESCE(cust_remark, '') AS cust_remark FROM ...`. I hope it helps!

Comment: @MichielOvertoom, COALESCE is ISNULL in SSIS :)

Comment: If you are selecting this data out of a table you could just write SQL to sort it out for you. This might be simpler than trying to use the unhelpful SSIS expression editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with the type cast inside the `ISNULL()` statement: try this.

```
(DT_STR, 150, 1252) (ISNULL([Serial No.]) ? "" :  [Serial No.])
```

If that doesn't work, try it with no casting statements at all:

```
(ISNULL([Serial No.]) ? "" :  [Serial No.])
```

Comment: I will accept your answer with explanation:
None of above worked alone.
I had to make a data conversion to String before I could use no. 2 example.
Thx :)